# PowerShell : Add New Key Value Pair In JSON File

Tags: arrays, json, powershell, powershell-3.0, powershell-cmdlet

**I want to add new key value in existing parsed json after specific index. For example : I have imported json in $json variable and then I wanted to add new property right after property name 'Service1'.**

**PowerShell Code :**

```
function Get-EnvironmentManifest([string]$Filename) {    
        $Settings = Get-Content -Path $Filename -Encoding UTF8 | ConvertFrom-Json -ErrorAction STOP 
        return $Settings
    }
    
if (([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($env:computerName)).HostName.Split('.')[0] -notmatch "UAT*") {
        $EnvironmentString = (([System.Net.Dns]::GetHostByName($env:computerName)).HostName.Split('.')[0].Split('-')[1]).ToUpper()
        for ($i = 1; $i -lt 5; $i++) {
            $ServiceName = 'Service' + [char](65 + $i)
            $HastTable = [ordered] @{"Name" = "Service1"; "ProfileType" = "Windows"; "ServiceName" = "$ServiceName";}            
            $Settings = Get-EnvironmentManifest -Filename $TargetJSON
            $Asset = New-Object -TypeName PSObject
            $Asset | Add-Member -NotePropertyMembers $HastTable -TypeName 'Asset'
            $Settings.Profiles.Services += $Asset
            $Settings | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 3| Set-Content -Path $TargetJSON        
        }    
    }
```

**I Was Able To Create Following JSON Using Above PowerShell Code :**

```
{
"Environment": {},
"Profiles": {
    "Services": [
        {
            "Name": "A"
        },
        {
            "Name": "B"
        },
        {
            "Name": "C"
        },
        {
            "Name": "D"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Service1",
            "ProfileType": "Windows",
            "ServiceName": "ServiceA"
        },
        {
            "Name": "E"
        },
        {
            "Name": "F"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Service1",
            "ProfileType": "Windows",
            "ServiceName": "ServiceB"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Service1",
            "ProfileType": "Windows",
            "ServiceName": "ServiceC"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Service1",
            "ProfileType": "Windows",
            "ServiceName": "ServiceD"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Service1",
            "ProfileType": "Windows",
            "ServiceName": "ServiceE"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

**But I Want To Have Following Json :**

```
{
"Environment": {},
"Profiles": {
    "Services": [
        {
            "Name": "A"
        },
        {
            "Name": "B"
        },
        {
            "Name": "C"
        },
        {
            "Name": "D"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Service1",
            "ProfileType": "Windows",
            "ServiceName": "ServiceA"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Service1",
            "ProfileType": "Windows",
            "ServiceName": "ServiceB"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Service1",
            "ProfileType": "Windows",
            "ServiceName": "ServiceC"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Service1",
            "ProfileType": "Windows",
            "ServiceName": "ServiceD"
        },
        {
            "Name": "Service1",
            "ProfileType": "Windows",
            "ServiceName": "ServiceE"
        },
        {
            "Name": "E"
        },
        {
            "Name": "F"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Comment: Please [format your code properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: What have you tried so far? Can you post any code you’ve already written and explain what’s working / not working.

Comment: Hi @mclayton : I have used following powershell code in order to add new property set. However, it is adding new property set at last of existing property sets.

Comment: Hi @mclayton :  I am putting a code in thread

Comment: Hi @mclayton : Any Help !!!